# Filtering a list of maps in clojure with potentially different keys

Tags: clojure

Say I have a list of maps that looks like the following:

```
(def my-map '({:some-key {:another-key "val"}
  :id "123"}
 {:some-key {:another-key "val"}
  :id "456"}
 {:some-other-key {:a-different-key "val2"}
  :id "789"})
```

In my attempt to filter this map by `:another-key`, I tried this:

`(filter #(= "val" ((% :some-key) :another-key)) my-map)))`

However, this will throw a `NullPointerException` on the map entry that doesn't contain the key I'm filtering on.  What would be the optimal way to filter this map, excluding entries that don't match the filtered schema entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first lookup of the key `:some-key` will return `nil` if the map key is not in the map. Calling `nil` will result in the NPE you see.

The solution is easy, just make the keyword lookup itself in the map which work even if given a nil:

```
(def my-map '({:some-key {:another-key "val"}
               :id "123"}
               {:some-key {:another-key "val"}
                :id "456"}
               {:some-other-key {:a-different-key "val2"}
                :id "789"}))

(filter #(= "val" (:another-key (% :some-key))) my-map)
```

You can also use `get-in`:

```
(filter #(= "val" (get-in % [:some-key :another-key])) my-map)
```

And if your list could potentially have `nil` items:

```
(filter #(= "val" (:another-key (:some-key %))) my-map)
```

Explanation:

```
(:k nil);; => nil
(nil :k);; => NPE
({:k 4} :k);; => 4
(:k {:k 4});; => 4
;; BTW, you can also specify the "not found" case:
(:k nil :not-there);; => :not-there
```

See also the [clojure style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#keywords-as-fn-to-get-map-values).